# Firing event when time changes on axwindowsmediaplayer

Tags: c#, winforms, wmplib

I have a windows application. I am using axwindowsmediaplayer which is in AxInterop.WMPLib dll.I dont have any problem about playing the videos, but I want to fire an event when the user goes to a specific time by clicking on media player . I looked in the dll files but i couldnt find such an event. Can anyone help me about how can i fire an event when user goes to another time on video ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about the [PositionChange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562462%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) event?

**Edit**

A short example:

```
public Form1()
{
  // ...
  axWindowsMediaPlayer1.PositionChange += axWindowsMediaPlayer1_PositionChange;
}

void axWindowsMediaPlayer1_PositionChange(object sender, AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PositionChangeEvent e)
{
  MessageBox.Show("The user changed the position from " + e.oldPosition + " to " + e.newPosition);
}
```